# How to find the direct link between the list elements?

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of connections that are possible between the elements, for example:

```
J&K - Punjab
J&K - Himachal Pradesh
Himachal Pradesh - Punjab
Himachal Pradesh - Haryana
Himachal Pradesh - Uttranchal
Punjab - Haryana
Punjab - Rajasthan
Punjab - UP
Haryana - Uttranchal
Haryana - Delhi
Haryana - Rajasthan
Haryana - Chhattisgarh
Haryana - Gujrat
Uttranchal - UP
Rajasthan - Gujrat
Rajasthan - Madhya Pradesh
Rajasthan - UP
Rajasthan - Delhi
UP - Delhi
UP - Madhya Pradesh
UP - West Bengal
UP - Bihar
UP - Assam
Chhattisgarh - Madhya Pradesh
Chhattisgarh - Maharashtra
Chhattisgarh - Tamil Nadu
Chhattisgarh - Orissa
Chhattisgarh - Jharkhand
Gujrat - Madhya Pradesh
Gujrat - Maharashtra
Madhya Pradesh - Maharashtra
West Bengal - Assam
West Bengal - Sikkim
West Bengal - Bihar
West Bengal - Jharkhand
West Bengal - Orissa
Bihar - Sikkim
Bihar - Jharkhan
Assam - Arunachal Pradesh
Assam - Nagaland
Assam - Manipur
Assam - Mizoram
Assam - Tripura
Assam - Meghalaya
Jharkhan - Orissa
Maharashtra - Goa
Maharashtra - Karnataka
Maharashtra - Telangana
Orissa - Karnataka 
Orissa - Andhra Pradesh
Goa - Karnataka
Karnataka - Telangana
Karnataka - Tamil Nadu
Karnataka - Kerala
Telangana - Andhra Pradesh
Tamil Nadu - Kerala
Tamil Nadu - Andhra Pradesh
```

So I want to find the direct link between the states. For example, if I say I want to find the links which are possible with `Rajasthan` then it should give us the output of all the possible direct links, like this:

```
Rajasthan - Gujrat
Rajasthan - Madhya Pradesh
Rajasthan - UP
Rajasthan - Delhi
Haryana - Rajasthan
Punjab - Rajasthan
```

I can't think of a possible logic for this, can anyone please help?

Comment: you could make a dictionary in which for each state you the list of possible links for that state. So in your example will look like `{"Rajashtan": ["Gujrat", "Madhya Pradesh", "UP", "Delhi"]`. So when you search, you could either check on the dictionary key for that state, or check each value for where the state is, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially what @Cristian already says in the comment, but you can do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# all_text is the text containing the plain string of the list you wrote above, with each line separated by \n
all_text = np.array(all_text.split('\n'))

connection = defaultdict(list)
for entry in all_text:
    entry = entry.split(' - ')
    connection[entry[0]].append(entry[1])
    connection[entry[1]].append(entry[0])

print(connection['Rajasthan'])
```

This returns `['Punjab', 'Haryana', 'Gujrat', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'UP', 'Delhi']`

Comment: hey can you give the example of all_text ?

Comment: all_text = '''J&K - Punjab
... all other lines ...
Tamil Nadu - Andhra Pradesh'''

(They must be separated by new lines)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple for loop like this:

```
connections_list = [
    'J&K - Punjab',
    'J&K - Himachal Pradesh']

for x in connections_list:
    _temp = x.split("-")
    for y in connections_list:
        if _temp[0] in y:
            print(y)
```